# Unable to connect to db after 5 min idle in Hibernate

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa, c3p0

I am using Hibernate in my spring application to connect to msql db.

It works fine when started, but I keep getting following error after keeping idle for about 5 min.

```
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
```

Not sure what's going wrong. 
Below is the code that I used for connection

```
@Bean
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean userMasterEntityManager() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        em.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.test.master" });

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);

        HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "none");
        properties.put("hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings", "false");
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");

        properties.put("hibernate.c3p0.min_size", "5");
        properties.put("hibernate.c3p0.max_size", "20");
        properties.put("hibernate.c3p0.timeout", "300");
        properties.put("hibernate.c3p0.max_statements", "50");
        properties.put("hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period", "3000");
        properties.put("hibernate.default_schema", "gmt_master");

        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);
        return em;
    }
```

Please let me know how to fix this issue,

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Your `hibernate.c3p0` settings are meaningless. You are injecting a preconfigured `DataSource` fix the timeout settings etc. on the datasource.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank you for your response, I will try to fix it in DataSource. It will be a great help, If you can provide me how connection pooling works at DataSource level. Thanks again. :)

Comment: Just configure a good datasource like HikariCP or C3P0... Which Datasource are y9ou using in your configuration?

Comment: According to my use case, the Datasource object will be created dynamically based on the user request params. I have extending AbstractDataSource and creating Datasource objects to connect to db (DB connection details will be part of the request of my API controller).

Answer (score 0):

You should change `hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period` to be less than `hibernate.c3p0.timeout`, such as

```
properties.put("hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period", "100");
```

You want to validate the idle connection in the pool before it's closed because of timeout.

Comment: Chancing the `hibernate.c3p0` settings is useless, as he is injecting a preconfigured datasource that takes precedence. He has to fix his datasource settings instead.